# передача данных и построение DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, scope

В angularjs передаю данные между контроллерами. Но не могу ее использовать.

```
$rootScope.$on('rootScope:emit', function (event, data) {
  $scope.echo = data;
  let input = document.getElementById('focus');
  console.log('INPUT', input);      
});
```

Далее вызываю функцию при ng-init элемента:

```
function getFocus(guide) {
  let input = document.getElementById('focus');

  console.log('ECHO', $scope.echo);
}
```

В итоге в консоли получаю null и undefined. Я понимаю, если бы либо одно, либо другое грузилось раньше. Может кто-нибудь объяснить, почему так происходит? И как это исправить?

Мне нужно при загрузке компонента проскроллить до нужного элемента, атрибут которого равен переданному значению. Но внутри $scope.$on проверка проходит успешно, но анимация не срабатывает. А вне прослушки вылазит проблема выше.

Вот так анимация не работает:

```
$scope.getFocus = function() {
  let input = document.getElementById('focus');     
  $rootScope.$on('rootScope:emit', function (event, data) {       
    if(input.getAttribute('name') == data) {
      console.log('OK');
      $timeout(function () {         
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
            scrollTop: $(input).offset().top - 65
        }, 1000);
      }, 500);          
    } else {
      console.log('NO');
    }           
  });    
}
```

Так не срабатывает условие, т.к. data всегда 0, даже если задержку перед условием поставить:

```
$scope.getFocus = function() {
  let input = document.getElementById('focus');
  let data = 0;  
  $rootScope.$on('rootScope:emit', function (event, data) {       
     data = data;   
  });
  if(input.getAttribute('name') == data) {
    console.log('OK');
    $timeout(function () {         
      $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
          scrollTop: $(input).offset().top - 65
      }, 1000);
    }, 500);          
  } else {
    console.log('NO');
  }    
}
```

Если же прослушивать вне метода, то html элемент null, либо свойство $scope.echo, куда записываю переданное значение, при проверки условия в методе еще не создано. Как будто сначала выполняется прослушка, потом строится DOM дерево и вызванный оттуда метод, а только после этого переданное значение записывается в $scope.echo. Ну это же бред.

Comment: нужен более полный пример. Приведенного кода недостаточно, чтобы сказать что не так.

Comment: дописал пример.

Comment: Нашел причину отсутствия свойства. $scope, который внутри $rootScope - это не тот скоуп, в котором я нахожусь. Это другой объект. Т.е. $scope.echo = data записывает данные в этот новый объект, а не в нужный скоуп.

Comment: нужен [mcve] например на plunker или подобном ресурсе, либо тут в [сниппете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999) Функции это хорошо, но нужно видеть где они объявлены и как вызываются.

Comment: sidenote: обычно нет нужды обращаться к DOM напрямую, лучше пользоваться возможностями предоставленными ангуляром

Answer (score 0):

короче, решил проблему, использовав в качестве хранения данных $rootScope, который виден из любого контроллера. Теперь просто беру оттуда необходимые данные, например:

Ctrl1:

```
Ctrl.autofocus = function(guide) {
    $rootScope.echo = guide.name;
}
```

Ctrl2:

```
$scope.entity.echo = $rootScope.echo}
```